# Where is it possible to find python documentation for training spacy model/pipelines

Tags: python, spacy-3

I have been looking through the spacy documentation on training/fine-tuning spacy models or pipelines, however, after walking through the following guide https://spacy.io/usage/training I found that it all comes down to creating and configuring a single file `config.cfg`. However, I didn't find a python guide to follow. Hence, I would like to know if this is the new norm, and if it is encouraged to follow this route rather than coding in python. Secondly, if there is a true python guide, I would love to get some references.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in spaCy v3 it is recommended you use the config file to control training, rather than writing Python code. Besides the main docs, there is an official walkthrough of the process [here](https://course.spacy.io/en/).